# Put legend to multiline plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I just cant find a way to put a legend to a simple plot. (I'm really new in R)

This is the plot. I need to identify each line.

[image]

my data:

```
Fecha     // Docente I // Docente II // Docente III // Docente IV // Docente V // Docente VI
2013-09-30 // 83.6723810 // 86.1640476 // 89.7185714 // 93.2509524 // 107.4069048 // 124.0100000
2013-10-31 // 77.7624358 // 80.0780669 // 83.3814834 // 86.6643654 // 99.8204992 // 115.2441140
2014-08-30 // 59.9288106 // 61.7136302 // 64.2593328 // 66.7895324 // 76.9284385 // 88.8149572
2014-09-01 // 59.9649293 // 61.7498651 // 64.3078666 // 66.8287472 // 76.9736700 // 88.8736376
2015-05-01 // 20.7348881 // 21.3520896 // 22.2366045 // 23.1082836 // 26.6162313 // 30.7310448
2015-11-01 // 12.1753399 // 12.5377551 // 13.0571343 // 13.5689764 // 15.6288118 // 18.0449933
2016-03-01 // 14.6043478 // 15.0391304 // 15.4069565 // 15.6600000 // 18.7469565 // 21.6452174
2016-06-01 // 16.9797794 // 17.4852941 // 18.2068015 // 18.9237132 // 21.7959559 // 25.1663603
2016-10-01 // 12.2737081 // 12.6394094 // 13.1607041 // 13.6791596 // 15.7552527 // 18.1930721
2017-02-01 // 6.6072389 // 6.8041086  // 7.0848618  //  7.3639032 // 8.4815358  //  9.7928589
2017-06-01 // 3.7889024 // 3.9018293  // 4.0628049  //  4.2228049 // 4.8637805  //  5.6157317
2017-10-01 // 0.8294410 // 0.8709026  // 0.9231591  //  0.9877890 // 1.0766784  //  1.2274120
2018-01-01 // 0.1687545 // 0.1771905  // 0.1878198  //  0.2009709 // 0.2190547  //  0.2497228
2018-03-01 // 7.3296962 // 7.6955894  // 8.1573399  //  8.7285811 // 9.5142462  // 10.0158413
```

Comment: Hi Ruben, your data is unusable as is. Please paste the output of `dput()` instead.

Comment: Please edit your post to include your plotting code also.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a potential solution using [pivot_longer()](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) to rearrange the data and make plotting easier:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Fecha = structure(c(15978, 16009, 16312, 16314, 
                                         16556, 16740, 16861, 16953, 17075, 17198, 17318, 17440, 17532, 
                                         17591), class = "Date"), `Docente I` = c(83.672381, 77.7624358, 
                                                                                  59.9288106, 59.9649293, 20.7348881, 12.1753399, 14.6043478, 16.9797794, 
                                                                                  12.2737081, 6.6072389, 3.7889024, 0.829441, 0.1687545, 7.3296962
                                         ), `Docente II` = c(86.1640476, 80.0780669, 61.7136302, 61.7498651, 
                                                             21.3520896, 12.5377551, 15.0391304, 17.4852941, 12.6394094, 6.8041086, 
                                                             3.9018293, 0.8709026, 0.1771905, 7.6955894), `Docente III` = c(89.7185714, 
                                                                                                                            83.3814834, 64.2593328, 64.3078666, 22.2366045, 13.0571343, 15.4069565, 
                                                                                                                            18.2068015, 13.1607041, 7.0848618, 4.0628049, 0.9231591, 0.1878198, 
                                                                                                                            8.1573399), `Docente IV` = c(93.2509524, 86.6643654, 66.7895324, 
                                                                                                                                                         66.8287472, 23.1082836, 13.5689764, 15.66, 18.9237132, 13.6791596, 
                                                                                                                                                         7.3639032, 4.2228049, 0.987789, 0.2009709, 8.7285811), `Docente V` = c(107.4069048, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                99.8204992, 76.9284385, 76.97367, 26.6162313, 15.6288118, 18.7469565, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                21.7959559, 15.7552527, 8.4815358, 4.8637805, 1.0766784, 0.2190547, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                9.5142462), `Docente VI` = c(124.01, 115.244114, 88.8149572, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             88.8736376, 30.7310448, 18.0449933, 21.6452174, 25.1663603, 18.1930721, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             9.7928589, 5.6157317, 1.227412, 0.2497228, 10.0158413)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), spec = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  cols = list(Fecha = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_date", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "collector")), `Docente I` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "collector")), `Docente II` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "collector")), `Docente III` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           "collector")), `Docente IV` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "collector")), `Docente V` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "collector")), `Docente VI` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Fecha) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Fecha, y = value,
             colour = name, group = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw(base_size = 18) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar,
                     name = "Sueldos") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Accent",
                     name = "Docentes")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It worked :) Thanks man. One last thing, how can i change the lines size and individual colors?

Comment: You can change the line size with e.g. `geom_line(size = 2)` and to change the colors, see http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-colors-how-to-change-colors-automatically-and-manually

Answer (score 1):

First bring your data in long format with `pivot_longer`.
then use `color`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df %>% 
    pivot_longer (
        cols = starts_with("Doc"),
        names_to = "Docente",
        values_to = "values"
    )

ggplot(df1, aes(x= Fecha, y=values, color=Docente)) + 
    geom_line() +
    theme_bw()
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(Fecha = structure(c(15978, 16009, 16312, 16314, 
16556, 16740, 16861, 16953, 17075, 17198, 17318, 17440, 17532, 
17591), class = "Date"), DocenteI = c(83.672381, 77.7624358, 
59.9288106, 59.9649293, 20.7348881, 12.1753399, 14.6043478, 16.9797794, 
12.2737081, 6.6072389, 3.7889024, 0.829441, 0.1687545, 7.3296962
), DocenteII = c(86.1640476, 80.0780669, 61.7136302, 61.7498651, 
21.3520896, 12.5377551, 15.0391304, 17.4852941, 12.6394094, 6.8041086, 
3.9018293, 0.8709026, 0.1771905, 7.6955894), DocenteIII = c(89.7185714, 
83.3814834, 64.2593328, 64.3078666, 22.2366045, 13.0571343, 15.4069565, 
18.2068015, 13.1607041, 7.0848618, 4.0628049, 0.9231591, 0.1878198, 
8.1573399), DocenteIV = c(93.2509524, 86.6643654, 66.7895324, 
66.8287472, 23.1082836, 13.5689764, 15.66, 18.9237132, 13.6791596, 
7.3639032, 4.2228049, 0.987789, 0.2009709, 8.7285811), DocenteV = c(107.4069048, 
99.8204992, 76.9284385, 76.97367, 26.6162313, 15.6288118, 18.7469565, 
21.7959559, 15.7552527, 8.4815358, 4.8637805, 1.0766784, 0.2190547, 
9.5142462), DocenteVI = c(124.01, 115.244114, 88.8149572, 88.8736376, 
30.7310448, 18.0449933, 21.6452174, 25.1663603, 18.1930721, 9.7928589, 
5.6157317, 1.227412, 0.2497228, 10.0158413)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

[image]